Calculate mean of group mean in R dplyr
Consider this dataframe:
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2), x = 1:5)

  id x
1  1 1
2  1 2
3  1 3
4  2 4
5  2 5

To get average x values per id, i use
df |> group_by(id) |> dplyr::summarise(group_mean = mean(x))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
     id group_mean
  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1        2  
2     2        4.5

I need to calculate the average of these group means, which is (2 + 4.5) / 2 = 3.25. However, this code fails:
df |> group_by(id) |> dplyr::summarise(group_mean = mean(x)) |> mean(group_mean)

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(dplyr::summarise(group_by(df, id), group_mean = mean(x)),  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Any suggestions?
EDIT:
This question is not similar to enter link description here as mentioned by @shizzle because i'm looking for the unbalanced mean of means, i.e., a second stage of aggregation and not for the first stage of calculating averages.

The data is unbalanced so the mean of the means does not equal the mean of the original x values.  Are you sure you want this?

This question is similar to: Calculate the mean by group. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@G.Grothendieck Thanks for your concerns, but this unbalanced mean is exactly what i need to calculate.

You could just pull the column with values and calculate the mean after like this:
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  dplyr::summarise(group_mean = mean(x)) |> 
  pull(group_mean) |>
  mean()
#> [1] 3.25

Created on 2024-07-31 with reprex v2.1.0

@margusl You are right my bad, thanks!

In base
> df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2), x = 1:5)
> mean(aggregate(x~id, df, mean)$x)
[1] 3.25


You can use mean + by like below
> with(df, mean(by(x, id, mean)))
[1] 3.25


A very short one. Or closer to aggregate: mean(tapply(df$x, df$id, mean))). (+1)

You need to ungroup your data and then calculate the mean of all values of the group_mean in a new column, like this:
df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  summarise(group_mean = mean(x)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(second_mean = mean(group_mean))

# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#      id group_mean second_mean
#   <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1        2          3.25
# 2     2        4.5        3.25

